# How to use If condition in function?

Tags: oracle19c

I am using oracle 19C on windows 10.
I want to create a function return the currency rate base on pass in ID as sample below:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE NONEDITIONABLE FUNCTION getexchangerate (
        oid IN VARCHAR2
    ) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
        exchangeoid   VARCHAR2(36 BYTE) := NULL;
        currency      VARCHAR2(10 BYTE);
        exrate        NUMBER(10, 4) := 0.0;
        l_ratethb     NUMBER(10, 2);
        l_rateusd     NUMBER(10, 2);
        l_rateeur     NUMBER(10, 2);
    BEGIN 
        IF ( oid != NULL ) THEN
            exchangeoid := regexp_substr(oid, '[^;]+', 1, 1);
            currency := regexp_substr(oid, '[^;]+', 1, 2);
        END
        
        IF exchangeoid != NULL THEN
            SELECT
                oid,
                ratethb,
                rateusd,
                rateeur
            INTO
                exchangeoid,
                l_ratethb,
                l_rateusd,
                l_rateeur
            FROM
                mexchange
            WHERE
                oid = exchangeoid;
        END
        
        IF CURRENCY !=NULL THEN
        
            IF CURRENCY = 'THB' THEN
                exrate := L_RATETHB;
            END
            IF CURRENCY ='USD' THEN
                exrate := L_RATEUSD;
            END
            IF CURRENCY = 'EUR' THEN
             exrate := l_rateeur;
            END
            
        END
        return exrate;
        
    END getexchangerate;
```

Above function error:

```
   Error(17,8): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "EXCHANGEOID" when expecting one of the following:     ;
```

The pass in value is (534534554xxxxx;USD)

Firstly, need to split oid from currency
then, select the row at oid string.
finally, return the rate base on pass in currency.

I have no idea to complete this function. I am young in PL/SQL.

Can anyone correct or suggest to me, please?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You';re missing lots of semicolons; and [an `IF` is finished with `END IF;`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-control-statements.html#GUID-B7DD4E62-3ED2-41E9-AAE5-90A78788BB31), not just `END`.

Comment: Pay attention to check `NULL`  by `is [not] null` and not `!=` or `=`

Comment: Yes, thank you I will correct this point.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I changed a bit and correct semicolons then it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had changed a bit something like this. It works.

```
   IF CURRENCY IS NOT NULL THEN
    
        IF CURRENCY = 'THB' THEN
            exrate := L_RATETHB;
        ELSIF CURRENCY ='USD' THEN
            exrate := L_RATEUSD;
        ELSE CURRENCY = 'EUR' THEN
            exrate := l_rateeur;
        END IF;
        
    END IF;
```

Thank you very much for your all suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

[From the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-control-statements.html#GUID-B7DD4E62-3ED2-41E9-AAE5-90A78788BB31):

> The IF THEN statement has this structure:
>
> ```
> IF condition THEN
>   statements
> END IF;
> ```

You are getting that error because you finish all your `IF` blocks with `END` instead of `END IF;`. That means it sees this:

```
...
    END
    
    IF exchangeoid != NULL THEN
```

as `END IF` and then sees `exchangeoid` where it expects to see a semicolon completing it.

As @Aleksej pointed out, you are also not handling nulls properly.

So this compiles; see inline comments:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE NONEDITIONABLE FUNCTION getexchangerate (
    oid IN VARCHAR2
) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
    exchangeoid   VARCHAR2(36 BYTE) := NULL;
    currency      VARCHAR2(10 BYTE);
    exrate        NUMBER(10, 4) := 0.0;
    l_ratethb     NUMBER(10, 2);
    l_rateusd     NUMBER(10, 2);
    l_rateeur     NUMBER(10, 2);
BEGIN 
    IF ( oid IS NOT NULL ) THEN -- changed != NULL to IS NOT NULL
        exchangeoid := regexp_substr(oid, '[^;]+', 1, 1);
        currency := regexp_substr(oid, '[^;]+', 1, 2);
    END IF; --- added IF;
    
    IF exchangeoid IS NOT NULL THEN -- changed != NULL to IS NOT NULL
        SELECT
            oid,
            ratethb,
            rateusd,
            rateeur
        INTO
            exchangeoid,
            l_ratethb,
            l_rateusd,
            l_rateeur
        FROM
            mexchange
        WHERE
            oid = exchangeoid;
    END IF; --- added IF;
    
    IF CURRENCY IS NOT NULL THEN -- changed != NULL to IS NOT NULL
    
        IF CURRENCY = 'THB' THEN
            exrate := L_RATETHB;
        END IF; --- added IF;
        IF CURRENCY ='USD' THEN
            exrate := L_RATEUSD;
        END IF; --- added IF;
        IF CURRENCY = 'EUR' THEN
         exrate := l_rateeur;
        END IF; --- added IF;
        
    END IF; --- added IF;
    return exrate;
    
END getexchangerate;
/
```

You could replace the three currency comparison `IF ... END IF;` blocks with `IF ... ELSIF ... ELSIF ... END IF;`, or a `CASE` statement. You can read about those options in the documentation too.